# how to update jobs to allow me to receive an email after the job finish running (slurm)

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, jobs, slurm

I have submitted several jobs on a computing cluster, but did not set the --mail-user. Can I update the specification now? Hope to receive emails after the jobs finish running. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure Slurm allows that. What you can do is submit a dummy job dependent on the already-submitted job (with jobid `<your-job-id>`), like this:

```
sbatch --mail-user=<your-email-address> --mail-type=START --dependency=afterany:<your-job-id> --wrap "echo OK"
```

so that this job will start only when the one you wanted to modify ends, and it will send an email then.

Comment: For me, I needed `--mail-type=BEGIN`.

Answer (score 2):

### This is not a solution

In PBS and derivatives you could update job attributes with `qalter` command. 
In SLURM some of the functions of `qalter` can be performed with `scontrol update`, however it does not seem to update the `mail-user` attribute.

The `scontrol update` command would look like

```
scontrol update jobid=<your-job-id> mail-user=<your-email-address>
```

However this command does not work as mentioned by *Damien Francois* in the comments. SLURM reports the following error:

```
Update of this parameter is not supported: 
    mail-user=<your-email-address> Request aborted
```

Comment: The suggested command fails with (Slurm version 15.08.11) ``Update of this parameter is not supported: mail-user=<your-email-address>
Request aborted``, and indeed the man page of scontrol does not mention any possibility of changing the email setting of the job.

Answer (score 1):

`MailUser` and `MailType` fields can be updated. The default `MailUser` is the submitting user, so it may only be necessary to update the `MailType`.

`scontrol update jobid=<jobid> MailUser=<user@domain.com>`

`scontrol update jobid=<jobid> MailType=<END,FAIL,...>`